# Input text is bold in Chrome, FF, Opera, but not in IE6.0. Why?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, text, input, cross-browser

I removed a lot of text, buttons etc, so this html page looks simplified. I still don't understand, why IE6.0 doesn't display the text "not bold in IE6.0. Why?" as bold?
Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
input[type='text'], input[type='password'], input[type='button'], input[type='submit'], input[type='file'], textarea {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;" value="bold" type="text"> 
<input type="text" value="not bold in IE6.0. Why?">
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE6 doesn’t support attribute selectors.

```
/* So, this would work in IE6: */
input { font-weight: bold; }

/* But IE6 won’t understand this: */
input[type="text"] { font-weight: bold; }

/* If you combine the two, IE6 still won’t understand it!
   It will drop the entire rule set, and it won’t apply any of its styles.
 */
input, input[type="text"] { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: Would you recommend to forget about this problem? It's just for the font in the input type text. How many people uses IE6.0-? less than 2%, and the other font is not critical... I've just googled it, and I  still don't know how to fix it. Thank you.  Ooops, seems like several times more than just 2% regarding review at ... for Jan 3rd, 2012.

Comment: @Haradzieniec Depending on the situation, you might get away with using `input { font-weight: bold; }`. If not, I don’t think it’s a big deal that IE6 users won’t get the bold text.